# Access multiple sqlite databases in one iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have 2 databases in my main bundle and I need to access both , in order to get their data and compare them,

When I try to access one of them separately I face no problem.
But when I try to access them both I get one database data not both!
 I use this function to intstantiate the DB

```
+(void) InstantiateYourDatabase:(NSString *)DatabaseName {
     / /Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;
NSString *dpname=DatabaseName;

_dbPath = [self getDBPath:dpname];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath];

NSLog(@"success == %i",success);

if( !success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:DatabaseName];
     success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:_dbPath error:&error];

    }  

}
```

and this to open the connection

```
+(void) openconnection
{ 
      NSString *rDBName=@"Encrypteed.sqlite";
   NSString *cDBKey =@"secret"; 

    if(sqlite3_open([_dbPath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {    
          NSLog(@"connection to the database,,opened");
    }
    else
          NSLog(@"connection failed");  
}
```

then in the view did load of another class I use

```
[SqliteClass InstantiateYourDatabase:@"db1.sqlite"];
[SqliteClass openconnection];

NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:  [SqliteClass getNames:@"names"]];

[SqliteClass InstantiateYourDatabase:@"db.sqlite"];
[SqliteClass openconnection];
 NSMutableArray *toCompareArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
[toCompareArray addObjectsFromArray:[SqliteClass getNames:@"Name"]];
```

Sqlite class is onther class where i have all the methods mentioned ,,, 'getNames' is also a class method ...
I get one database data ,,,
I tried many tin=mes ,,there is no wrong in any of my databases ,I searched in google without any good hint ,,

but am thinking that multithreading is a solution though I have no idea about multithreading

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class methods and variables to access multiple databases, that's just not going to work. I assume that `_dbPath` is a static variable so you can access it in your class method? If that is the case, the second time you call `InstantiateYourDatabase` you are changing this value.

I would create a data access service (can be a singleton) which manages an dictionary holding your database details, you can then access each one via the appropriate key.

Comment: well i tried to use object of SqliteClass and instance methods in another app. with the same old result,, I get the error msg ,,No such table found: nameOfTable,, _dbPath is static string,, 
can u give me a hint about creating such service u  suggested!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using CoreData? It simplifies this greatly!

Comment: using sqlite directly   would be faster ,, I didn't use even any wrapper ,,
For now it works I just used 2 open methods instead of accessing one open method ,,with   'MAC OS' app rather than IOS ,,,I dont have any Idea why that !!! but it sustain my need for now ,,
and thnx alot for ur time ..